# Getting a count of values in a list (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

My data looks roughly like the following:

```
Col 1 Col 2
A,B,C 150
A,B   300
```

How can I get the count of values in column 1? Ultimately, I need to divide the values in column 2 by that count.

Edit: all of these are super helpful — thanks!

Comment: What does the _count_ mean in this context? Is the count of the first row 1 (because it exists), or 3 (because it contains A B and C), or 5 (because it contains 5 characters)?

Comment: 3. Should have clarified better. So it would be 150/3, 300/2, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @a='a,b,c';

select (length(@a) - length(replace(@a,',','')) ) + 1 nofvalues;

+-----------+
| nofvalues |
+-----------+
|         3 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Assuming there are no repeated values

Comment: Thank you!! This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the length of the first column (minus the commas) as the basis for this:

```
SELECT Col1,
       Col2,
       Col2 / LENGTH(REPLACE(Col1, ',' ,'')) AS OutputValue
  FROM TestTable
```

Output:

```
Col1    Col2    OutputValue
A,B,C   150     50
A,B     300     150
```

This works by:

1. Replacing the commas with an empty string (`REPLACE(...)`) (`A,B,C` -> `ABC`)
2. Determining the length of the resulting text (`LENGTH(...)`) (`ABC` -> 3)
3. Dividing `Col2` by the length from step 2 (`150 / 3` -> `50`)

An example fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/619611/5).

Answer (score 1):

```
select *,  
  length(col1) - length(replace(col1, ',', '')) + 1 counter,
  col2 / (length(col1) - length(replace(col1, ',', '')) + 1) result
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dbVLmJiaywpVXHX1LEE1eo/2).
Results:

```
| Col1  | Col2 | counter | result |
| ----- | ---- | ------- | ------ |
| A,B,C | 150  | 3       | 50     |
| A,B   | 300  | 2       | 150    |
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think if this is proper solution but this should work in your case:

```sql
SELECT 
    LENGTH(`col1`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`col1`, ',', '')) + 1 as count,
    col2

-- if you want to get col2 divided by that count 
--    col2 / (
--        LENGTH(`col1`) - LENGTH(REPLACE(`col1`, ',', '') + 1
--    ) as divided

FROM 'mytable'
```

Hope this helps you.